# How do you find the group-wise max in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, max, groupwise

I'm trying to solve the "group-wise max" problem in LINQ.  To start, I have a database modeled using the Entity Framework with the following structure:

```
Customer:
---------
CustomerID : Int32
Name : String

Order:
-------
OrderID : Int32
CustomerID : Int32
Total : Decimal
```

This gives me navigation from a Customer to her orders and an Order to the owner.

I'm trying to create a LINQ query that allows me to find the top-10 customer orders in the database.  The simple case was pretty easy to come up with:

```
var q = (
    from order in _data.Orders  // ObjectQuery<Order>
    orderby order.Amount descending select order
).Take(10);
```

However, I'd like to only show unique customers in this list.  I'm still a bit new to LINQ, but this is what I've come up with:

```
var q = (
    from order in _data.Orders  // ObjectQuery<Order>
    group order by order.Customer into o
    select new {
        Name = o.Key.Name,
        Amount = o.FirstOrDefault().Amount
    }
).OrderByDescending(o => o.Amount).Take(10);
```

This seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach.  Specifically, I wonder about the performance of such a query against a very large database.  Also, using the `FirstOrDefault` method from the group query looks a little strange...

Can anyone provide a better approach, or some assurance that this is the right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
var q = (
    from order in _data.Orders  // ObjectQuery<Order>
    orderby order.Amount descending select order
).Distinct().Take(10);
```

I would normally look at the generated SQL, and see what is the best.

Comment: That brings up a great question...  How do I look at the generated SQL?  With the LINQ to SQL DataContext, I could log the output.  I haven't found a way to do that for EF.

Comment: Hrm...  Trying this, I had to create a custom equality comparator (since the default one doesn't work for this purpose).  However, this throws an exception saying that EF doesn't recognize that method.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Customer
.Select(c=>new {Order= c.Orders.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Total).First()})
.OrderByDescending(o=>o.Total)
.Take(10);
```