# How to get the max timestamp and groupby another field in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, grouping

I have an Entity with the following fields
GUID TaskId,
GUID SubTaskId,
DateTime    Timestamp

The TaskId may be one-to-many with the SubTaskId. It's like a composite key almost.

I would like to write an expression or expressions resulting in the newest among each TaskId
i.e.

TaskId  SubTaskId   Timestamp
1   A   *2010-11-22 15:48:49.727*
1   B   *2010-11-22 16:24:51.117*
2   C   *2010-11-15 11:49:05.717*
2   D   *2010-11-15 14:02:11.467*

Would result in a sequence containing only:
TaskId  SubTaskId   Timestamp
1   B   *2010-11-22 16:24:51.117*
2   D   *2010-11-15 14:02:11.467*

This expression works just fine for showing all TaskId's and TimeStamps

```
var q1 = 
    from req in myEntity
    orderby req.TaskId
    select new
    {
        req.TaskId,
        req.SubTaskId,
        req.Timestamp
    };
```

but I would like to show only the latest Timestamp for each TaskId. All my attempts at adding a max to the expression fail. The posting (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034800/how-do-you-find-the-group-wise-max-in-linq) seemed close, but I couldn't translate it into something working. Perhaps a `foreach` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
var q1 = 
    from req in myEntity
    group req by req.TaskId into g
    let topReq = g.OrderByDescending(r => r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()
    select new
    {
        topReq.TaskId,
        topReq.SubTaskId,
        topReq.Timestamp
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var tasks = new[] { 
new { TaskId = 1, SubTaskId = "A", Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-22 15:48:49.727")},
new { TaskId = 1, SubTaskId = "B", Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-22 16:24:51.117")},
new { TaskId = 2, SubTaskId = "C", Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-15 11:49:05.717")},
new { TaskId = 2, SubTaskId = "D", Timestamp = DateTime.Parse("2010-11-15 14:02:11.467")}};


var newestTasks = 
    from task in tasks
    group task by task.TaskId into g
    select g.Where(t => t.Timestamp == g.Max(t2 => t2.Timestamp)).Single();

foreach (var task in newestTasks)
    Console.WriteLine("TaskId = {0}, SubTaskId = {1}, Timestamp = {2}", 
        task.TaskId, task.SubTaskId, task.Timestamp);
```

Comment: Nice. I like the way you put the test together. I'll be sure to construct the sequence like this next time I have a question in LINQ. This works quite well.

Comment: Alas, Single is not supported by LINQ to Entities, although your example, as it is, does work well.